# EditText Number Formatting (ex: 123.456,23) Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, textwatcher

I need to format my EditText in real time with the format (###.###,##) i tried everything i could find and nothing seems to work for my case
example 1: if a user input '23' the result should be '0.23'
example 2: if a user input '11123456' the result should be '111.234,56'

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the [`TextWatcher`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher) interface for this. The [`afterTextChanged`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher#afterTextChanged(android.text.Editable)) callback will fire whenever the contents of the `EditText` are modified, and you can make further modifications yourself within this callback (taking care to avoid recursive entry).

Something like this should get you close, at least:

```
class NumericFormattingTextWatcher : TextWatcher {
  private val formatter = NumberFormat.getInstance()
  private var skipNextChange = false
  
  override fun afterTextChanged(content: Editable) {
    if (skipNextChange) return

    skipNextChange = true
    val formatted = formatter.format(content.toString())
    content.replace(0, content.length(), formatted, 0, formatted.length())
    skipNextChange = false
  }

  override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {}
  override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {}
}
```

Then add this on your `EditText`:

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(NumericFormattingTextWatcher())
```

You'll also want to handle invalid input when formatting (e.g. if the user enters "11.22.33.44").